# P3D sketch not working in Python mode of Processing

Tags: processing

I was translating a **Java** sketch to a **Python** sketch in **Processing**. It is using the **P3D** engine and it is not showing anything in the window while it is showing *what I want* in **Java** mode. When I run it just shows a **blank black window** instead of a grid. I can change its background color but I can not draw in the shapes or something window. Please help me! And I can not share its code as it is *not an open source project*.

Comment: If you cannot share the code, maybe you can create an "example project" in the same conditions and share it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. It was a mistake in the code. I was making the grid using for loop and the variables that were needed for **for loop** were not defined properly it was not giving an error because the value of variables was 0. Sorry for wasting your time. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and closing this issue. Glad you did it!